# How does $DEBUG variable get set when running a Ruby script

Tags: debugging, command-line-arguments

I tried running the script test.rb, containing:

```
puts "Debugging" if $DEBUG
```

using the command:

```
> ruby test.rb --debug
```

The --debug switch seems to have no effect.  What gives?

Comment: This does work as expected: `ruby -e "puts $DEBUG"  --debug`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duh... debug parameter needs to be passed to Ruby.

```
> ruby --debug test.rb
```

works as expected.